# Do all imported arrays in Vue.js have to be reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm importing a simple array of 4 strings called `QUIZ_DATA` into my Vue.js component:

```js
["Question1?", "Question number 2?", "This is number 3!", "And # 4"]
```

These 4 questions are static and won't change. I don't need them to be reactive, so I import them into my component as `QUIZ_DATA`, but when I try to iterate through the array, it gives me an error that the property is non-reactive.

```vue
<template>
    <div v-for="(question, index) in QUIZ_DATA">
        {{ question }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import QUIZ_DATA from "~/plugins/QuizData.js";

export default {
    // Nothing here yet
}
</script>
```

The console says:

> Make sure that this property is reactive.

I got rid of the error by copying the array into my component's data object, which feels like an unnecessary step, given that the array won't change:

`data(){return {quizData: QUIZ_DATA}}`

Is there a way of iterating through static objects without needing to copy them into the component's `data()` object first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QUIZ_DATA` must be a property of the component instance if you want to access it from within the template.

Non-reactive data can be assigned to the component instance in the `created` hook.

```js
created() {
  this.QUIZ_DATA = QUIZ_DATA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return your array with computed property:

```js
const QUIZ_DATA = ["Question1?", "Question number 2?", "This is number 3!", "And # 4"]
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  computed: {
    questions() {
      return QUIZ_DATA
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in questions">
    {{ question }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of iterating through static objects without needing to
> copy them into the component's data() object first ?

Answer is `Yes`, ways to achieve **:**

- By using `computed` property.

```js
const QUIZ_DATA = ["Question1?", "Question number 2?", "This is number 3!", "And # 4"];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    QUIZ_DATA() {
      return QUIZ_DATA
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in QUIZ_DATA">
    {{ question }}
  </div>
</div>
```

- As data is `non-reactive` we can use `created` hook.

```js
let QUIZ_DATA = ["Question1?", "Question number 2?", "This is number 3!", "And # 4"];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function () {
    this.QUIZ_DATA = QUIZ_DATA;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in QUIZ_DATA">
    {{ question }}
  </div>
</div>
```